# What exactly defines a LAN?

Tags: networking, local-area-network

When I am reading some networking books, they often define a LAN as a set of connected computers across a building, campus floor, home, etc. However, I think this is pretty vague. What exactly defines a LAN? i.e. when looking at a network topology, how can you identify a LAN?

Comment: Local would by definition be anything that's not "remote". Which then extends the question to what's "remote". One safe-ish way to go is anything that's not connected via a bridge/router/gateway.

Answer (score 6):

I found this nice definition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN):

```
A local area network (LAN) is a computer network that interconnects computers in
a limited area such as a home, school, computer laboratory, or office building.
The defining characteristics of LANs, in contrast to wide area networks (WANs),
include their usually higher data-transfer rates, smaller geographic area,
and lack of a need for leased telecommunication lines.
```

So, the three points that you can count on to decide whether this is a LAN or not use:

1. Smaller geographic area.
2. Higher data rates.
3. Lack of leased lines to interconnect its parts.

Answer (score 3):

There is no precise definition, nor would it be useful.

In some situations, it might make sense to speak of a LAN as one broadcast domain; in another situation it might mean every node in a building; in yet another, two buildings connected with fiber.

The wikipedia quote posted earlier will have to do.

Comment: Exactly. If it's hard to decide whether a particular network is a WAN or a LAN, it would only be because neither term accurately described it. In that case, what would be the point of calling it one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty generic term. Any Local Area Network can consist of a number of computers <2 connected by a means.

Comment: I'd say it has at least a bit to do with the trust that you can afford to a physically restricted network, as well as shared resources (like internet connections).

Comment: Thanks, but that really doesn't answer my question, since I was wondering what the _precise_ definition of a LAN is :)